# Unknown column in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am performing this query:

```
SELECT C.id, C.content, C.video_id,C.username, C.date_sent, SUM(V.vote) AS vote_total
            FROM comments C 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN comments_votes V 
            ON C.id=V.comment_id 
            WHERE c.video_id = '5'
            GROUP BY C.id, C.content, C.username, C.video_id, C.date_sent, C.video_id
            ORDER BY C.content ASC
```

And it works fine on my localhost which runs `10.1.21-MariaDB` but my host operates on `mySQL 5.7` and when I run the above I get:

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'c.video_id' in 'where clause'

I am not very knowledgable on SQL but I tried to do some research on SO but most solutions point to a bug in 5.5.

My comments table is this:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Well... does the column exist or not?  Please show your table structures.

Comment: @Siyual Yes it does.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mariadb` and I've never seen it be an issue before with other DBMS's, but that is the only reference to that column using a lower-case `c` instead of an upper-case `C`.  Have you tried changing the alias?

Comment: AS @this.lau_ stated below, you have a linked comments as `C` (uppercase), but you're trying to access `c.video_id`. Maria is case sensitive on table names

Comment: @DaveyBoy, he said it works in Maria

Comment: @DaveyBoy - It depends on OS and a few other things - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-case-sensitivity/

Comment: In that case, as the OP actually tried changing the case of `c.video_id` to `C.video_id`? We don't know what OS is being used

Comment: @DaveyBoy @Siyual using lowercase `c` instead of `C` as suggested by this.lau_ worked. It seems like my host is not case insensitive and thus was declaring an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one instance is configured as case-insensitive and the other not. Try to change to `C.video_id` (or better yet, never use uppercase in database identifiers).

Comment: Case sensitivity depends on the underlying OS because tables are saved as file(s). [More details here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: It looks like it depends on the config "lower_case_table_names", which in turn affects table aliases. So basically the underlying file system doesn't matter much if all his tables are lowercase anyway, however that particular setting is going to affect how the table aliases are resolved, which it seems is what's happening here.

Comment: Excerpt from the link of my previous comment: _This means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case sensitive in most varieties of Unix._ and _The lower_case_table_names system variable_ **also** _affects how the server handles identifier case sensitivity, as described later in this section._ so the OS does matter.